# Suggestions for refinishing suspension springs

Tags: suspension, paint, underbody, chassis-paint

Can anyone suggest a tried and tested method for refinishing suspension springs.  The springs I have at the moment have shed their protective coating which I assume was some sort of powder coating?

I'm looking for a finish I can apply that will be durable enough but also flexible enough as I know the springs constantly expand and contract whilst driving.

I'd considered straight auto body paint, a plasticoat style plastic based paint, threading "heat shrink" over the length of the spring and heating it to the required temperature.

I wondered if anyone had actually refinished their springs and what level of finish and longevity they've had.

Comment: The heat shrink suggestion made me smile.  I have no idea what results you would get, but I would love to see the process and finished product.

Comment: @JPhi1618 we've used heatshink on the steering arms of the caterham with very satisfactory results.  It effectively creates a complete plastic coating over the metal.

Comment: That's cool for sure.  I wasn't being dismissive, I really wanted to know if it would work well.  It seems like it would when I imagine it, but its awesome that it has actually been done.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very best solution is to powder-coat them - but you need to get them to a paint-ready condition before you take them to the powder-coating company; otherwise, it could cost quite a bit. Harbor Freight sell powder-coating kits, but I've never tried them, and if this is a one-off job, sending it to a company will be the most cost-effective solution.

Another alternative is caliper paint. You won't need to work as hard to clean the springs as you would for powder-coating, but the better the surface preparation, the better the finish.

Comment: At home powder coat: _"You want to put_ what _in the oven?!?"_

Comment: @JPhi1618 I have put both cylinder heads and brake calipers in the dish washer before so putting springs in the over probably wouldn't cause too much surprise in our house.

Answer (score 2):

Aerospace landing gear applications usually require springs to be coated in Duralon (name brand), which is a Nylon compound that is applied much like a powder coat. It is used for its flexibility, impact and corrosion resistance, and it provides a smooth, clean finish so damage and defects are easier to visibly identify.